# How to make core client-side JS functions availabe in TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I have a TS project that uses Node, express, and handlebars.  I also have some client-side JS that it uses with no problem.  (Clarification: not using react, angular, vue, or any other client-side framework at the moment.)

I was looking into moving the client-side JS into TS as well.  My Hello World example tries to use alert (literally `alert("Hello World");`) but won't compile (error: `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'alert'.`).  Should be a simple enough, I just need to discover the module to import into the file (or the dependency to add to my package.config) to make core client-side JavaScript function available.

I can't seem to find the reference for how to do this (outside of a wealth of library-specific examples in angular, react, etc.).

So what dependency and/or import am I looking for to expose core client-side JS functions and the like to my TS project?

Answer (score 1):

Ah.

The "lib" property of my tsconfig only included es2017.  Added DOM and that fixed it.